# Calculate SNR if I have the noise?

Tags: signal-processing, simulation, wavelets, noise

I am looking for ways to calculate signal-to-noise ratio (SNR). As I understand it, this measure is often used when you have a separated clean signal and noisy signal, and can thus measure the power in order to get the SNR. The formula being
$$
\text{SNR} = \frac{P_{signal}}{P_{noise}}.
$$
This is pretty straightforward in the case of having a clean signal and having the noise, separated.

What I am after is in the case of not having this separation, but just a noisy signal. What I do have is the actual noise. Basically two signals being:

1. The main signal, i.e. a noisy signal which I want to denoise
2. A signal made up of only noise (coming from lab equipment etc.)

Is there any good way of calculating a similar noise measurement as the SNR? I am denoising with wavelets and I am having a hard time actually evaluating wether the denoising was successful or not when it comes to this data. Also, I am basing the best result of SNR which at the moment is pretty unsuccessful.

For simulated data it works great, though, using the SNR definition in the formula above, reason being I have the two separated channels.

Hopefully I have explained it good enough so it is understandable. :)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If the noise is moderate, you can just neglect its effect on the signal power. An improvement is to assume that the signal and noise are uncorrelated so that the powers add up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Okay, so you're saying that I can measure the SNR via (denoised signal)/(noisy signal) sort of? Would be great if you could elaborate a bit :)

Comment: No, I said Psignal ~ Pnoisy - Pnoise.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Tired brain! Makes sense, I will try this estimator out. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(extended comment)

You are effectively dealing with a parameter estimation problem: Estimate the parameter 'SNR' given the observed (noisy) signal. Other than that, nothing more can be said from your description. A decent estimator would consider aspects such as (main) signal properties and noise distribution (if available). It seems that you have this information to some extent (you claim you can obtain a denoised version of the signal), which could lead to an SNR estimator such as (denoised signal)/(noisy signal - denoised signal). How good this estimate is can only be statistically described and you would need to use some signal and noise model for simulation and/or analytical work.

Comment: I am in the situation where a simulated signal can be denoised pretty well. But this is since I am basing my denoising on SNR (the highest SNR -> the best denoising). So the SNR is not actually the goal itself but is enabling my denoising. Therefore I would like to have some way of calculating a similar measurement to the SNR provided I have the noisy signal and noise. The comment from Yves Daoust might make some sense, I will try it out.